# Display table header depending on the number of columns Java

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to build a database reader that displays strings but I am trying to line up the table to display 4 columns with the headers (ID, Name, userName, password). What I have so far is it is displaying 8 columns with the headers (ID, Name, userName, password) when I only want 4 displayed. The "data" variable in the loop has two sets of String values so I believe that's why it is displaying 8 columns.

```java
private void populateTextArea(ObservableList<List<String>> data) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<table style=\"margin: auto; width: 90%; \" border=\"1\">");
    builder.append("<caption>Test Table</caption>");
    builder.append("<tr style=\"height: 2rem;\">");
    for (List COLUMN_NAMES : data) {
        builder.append("<th>ID</th>");
        builder.append("<th>Nickame</th>");
        builder.append("<th>Usename</th>");
        builder.append("<th>Password</th>");
    }

    builder.append("</tr>");
    builder.append("</table>");
    webView.getEngine().loadContent(builder.toString());
}
```

```java
private ObservableList<List<String>> search(String searchTerm) throws SQLException {
    ObservableList<List<String>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.add(List.of("3", "James", "admin", "admin"));
    list.add(List.of("2", "jaylen", "admin", "admin"));

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `for` loop. But keep the four `<th>` appender statements which are currently inside the `for` loop. (By the way, this does not appear to be a DataTables question - so you should probably remove that tag from your question).

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you for the help, will remove tag!

Comment: You were 90% of the way to the solution already - your instincts were correct.

Answer (score 3):

You're looping over `data`, which seems to have two items, so the loop runs twice, adding the column headers twice.

Simple solution: remove the loop.

Comment: Thank you I went ahead and fixed it up.

Answer (score 2):

My new resolved answer.

```
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        builder.append("<table style=\"margin: auto;width: 90%;\" border=\"1\">");
        builder.append("<caption>Test Table</caption>");
        builder.append("<tr style=\"height: 2rem;\">");
        
        builder.append("<th>ID</th>");
        builder.append("<th>Nickame</th>");
        builder.append("<th>Usename</th>");
        builder.append("<th>Password</th>");
        builder.append("</tr>");

        for(List<String>row : data) {
            builder.append("<tr>");
            for(String values : row) {
                builder.append("<td>"+values+"</td>");
            }
           builder.append("</tr>");
        }

        builder.append("</tr>");
        builder.append("</table>");
        
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(builder.toString());
    }
    private ObservableList<List<String>> search(String searchTerm) throws SQLException {

        ObservableList<List<String>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        list.add(List.of("3", "James", "admin", "admin"));
        list.add(List.of("2", "jaylen", "admin", "admin"));
        return list;
    }
```